# symfony debug:true does what?

Tags: symfony

I've been searching symfony docs and SO for an explanation of what changing symfony's `debug` flag to `true` does exactly. I feel stupid for not finding it ... can anyone provide a link to the doc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read [Working with environments](http://symfony.com/doc/current/quick_tour/the_big_picture.html#working-with-environments) for more informations about the debug.

You are right, the Symfony Documentation related to the [Debug component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/debug/introduction.html) will help for use it but not give detailed explanations about the features added to the environment.

If you use `debug=true` in your environment, you will get the debug-bar containig all informations related to your environment, and other features related to debug in a PHP framework.

I will list the main additional features added by enabling debug :

- Toolbar added with all informations about requests, security, deprecations, translations, configuration, and errors in your current request.
- Cache files are dynamically rebuilt on each request.
- Enable debugging features in packages and third-party libraries based on debug (such as Twig `dump`)

Errors displaying are no longer managed by the debug, it's just configured in the front-controller (e.g. `app_dev.php` and `app.php`)

Informations coming from [Configuration and environments](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/configuration.html#page-creation-environments)
Symfony documentation is very vast and it's surely not the bigger part, but very important to know, I discover it too.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but as I am sure you already know, while `env` and `debug` are related, they are different settings that are somewhat independent. I am looking specifically for information on the `debug` parameter. I already knew about the toolbar and full traces on exceptions/errors, but I want to know ALL the details.

Comment: I've added more details in my answer.

Comment: the expanded information is very helpful thank you. It seems odd to me that there is no exhaustive list or doc that provides this information somewhere on symfony's docs.

Comment: I've added the source link of the informations coming from doc but not very visible. No problem, thank's for your good question.